# Effect of an increase/decrease of ρ or θ on consumption per effective labour and on capital per effective labour? And on their steady-state values?

Tags: macroeconomics

In a Ramsey-Cass-Koopmans framework, having defined ρ as the rate of time preference, I was wondering what is the effect of a variation in the two parameters on consumption per effective labour and on capital per effective labour and on their steady state values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f$ is the Cobb-Douglas production function in per capita terms, then is the steady-state equilibrium consumption $c^*$ and capital $k^*$  uniquely determined by
$$f'(k^*) = \delta + \rho \quad \text{and} \quad c^* = f (k^*) - (n + \delta) k^*$$
with depreciation rate $\delta$, time preference $\rho$, and growth rate $n$.

Since $f$ is assumed to be Cobb-Douglas it holds $f' > 0$ and $f'' < 0$. Hence is $f$ strictly monotone increasing and $f'$ strictly monotone decreasing.
Thus, for $\tilde \rho$ with $\tilde \rho < \rho$,
we have
$$f'(k^*) = \delta + \rho \quad \text{and} \quad f'(\tilde k^*) = \delta + \tilde \rho,$$
and since $f'$ is strictly monotone decreasing we have that $\tilde k^* > k^*$ holds.
By usind that $f$ is strictly monotone increasing we obtain by
$$c^* = f (k^*) - (n + \delta) k^* \quad \text{and} \quad \tilde c^* = f (k^*) - (n + \delta) k^*$$
that $\tilde c^* > c^*$ holds, too.

In [Introduction to Modern Economic Growth by Daron Acemoglu](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691132921/introduction-to-modern-economic-growth) does Proposition 8.3 yield the sensitivity analysis for all parameters.

Comment: Thank you! To tell the truth I still don’t get why ̃∗ is greater than the other if its first derivative is lower.

Comment: @tryingtogetsmth I accidentally described $f'$ as monotone increasing at the very end which as been fixed. Clearly $f'$ is strictly **decreasing**, and, thus, the inverse is strictly decreasing, too, i.e., for $\tilde \rho < \rho$ we have that $\tilde k^* > k^*$.
You have to see $k^*$ as function in dependency of $\rho$, i.e., $k(\rho) = f'^{-1}(\delta + \rho)$

Comment: Ok now it makes sense, thank you indeed!